# WhatsApp Call Locks iPhone in black screen, doesn't respont to touch

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

In order to be more specific, I would like to describe what is going on by example. Let's say I receive a call in WhatsApp messenger I get it and put the phone to my ear, when I do this the proximity sensor tracks that the phone is near my ear and the screen goes to a black screen (in order to prevent unintentional touch input). But the problem is that after I take the phone away from my ear, the screen is still black and there is no way to use it except to force restart (turn off and on) the device.

I noticed that it happens only with WhatsApp messenger.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix it?

**UPD1**

[image]

Comment: Which iOS do you run? Can you try checking if a WhatsApp update is available via the App Store?

Comment: @anonymous added `UPD1` as you can see the version is `15.1` and Whatsup doesn't have available updates on the market.